# how to set different port for different virtualdomains on different apache servers on same pc (runing Ubuntu16)

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-16.04

I have a local server running Ubuntu16, with two php versions installed:

- php5.6 for old sites
- php7 for new ones.

Running two apache instances for the two php installs.
One of the apache2 listens on port 80 with php7, this is the default one, 
the other apache2-php5 listens on port 81 with php5.6.

I have multiple virtual domains on this machine, one (domain1.local) configured for php5.6 and I can access this virtual domain like this:

domain1.local:81

So my question is how to set up the server to access domain1.local without the port number(apache2-php5 php5.6 port 81), and other virtual domains without port number (apache2 php7 on port 80)

On apache2-php5 sites-available conf file I have the port number set to 81 for domain1.local and on apache2 sites-available conf files for other virtual domains I have the port number set on 80.
On both apache2 port.conf I have the 81 respective 80 set to Listen.

So what am I missing here ?
Thanx.

Comment: You _cannot_ have two servers listening on the same port. Period. What you _can_ do is that you proxy one behind the other. That way the front end server serves _all_ virtual hosts ("domains"), whilst the back end server processes half of the requests which are simply handed through to an internal port by the front end server.

Comment: Can I redirect somehow this specific virtual domain to port 81? Some alias of something ?

Comment: As already said: yes, you can proxy it. What you are looking for is either apaches proxy module or you can use the rewriting module on top. And you want to proxy a "virtual host". There is no such thing as a "virtual domain". I suggest you simply refer to the documentation. It comes with really good examples for this stuff.